# Run multiple ps1 scripts using single master ps1

Tags: powershell

I am trying to run a ps1 script for different action multiple times and need to output the result to a text file.

**Example:**

```
C:\Program Files\script folder> .\script.ps1 version 
C:\Program Files\script folder> .\script.ps1 status
etc
```

I have 15 such commands to run sequentially. How do I collate all this into a master ps1 and run sequentially and output the result to a text file?

```
$scriptsList = 
@(
    'C:\Program Files\script folder> .\script.ps1 version ' >> C:\TEMP\output.txt
    'C:\Program Files\script folder> .\script.ps1 status' >> C:\TEMP\output.txt
)

for each($script in $scripts List)
{
   Start-Process -File Path "$PSHOME\powershell.exe" -Argument List "-command ' $script'" -Wait

}
```

The output file doesn't show actual output instead below is shown as output in the text file.

```
C:\Program Files\script folder> .\script.ps1 version 
C:\Program Files\script folder> .\script.ps1 status
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Invoke-Expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-expression?view=powershell-6) to do so. Place all commands in the `master.ps1` as shown below -

```
Invoke-Expression "\\PathToYourScript\Script1.ps1"
Invoke-Expression "\\PathToYourScript\Script2.ps1"
Invoke-Expression "\\PathToYourScript\Script3.ps1"
Invoke-Expression "\\PathToYourScript\Script1.ps1"
```

This will result in the scripts being called sequentially.

**OR**

Make use of `Split-Path` along with the `$MyInvocation` automatic variable. If all the child scripts are in the same folder then you can probably add this in your `master.ps1` file -

```
& ((Split-Path $MyInvocation.InvocationName) + "\Script1.ps1")
& ((Split-Path $MyInvocation.InvocationName) + "\Script2.ps1")
& ((Split-Path $MyInvocation.InvocationName) + "\Script3.ps1")
```

Comment: `"Invoke-Expression "C:\Program Files\Illumio\illumio-ven-ctl.ps1 version"` **-->** `Invoke-Expression "C:\Program Files\Illumio\illumio-ven-ctl.ps1 version"`

You are having extra double-quotes.

Comment: @user11753358 - If the above solution solved your problem, please check the `tick` mark and mark the answer as an accepted working solution. It may help others in the future.